# showing QMessageBox with QThread when GUI frozen

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qthread

Qt GUI frozen when I did some plotting works. I want to show "loading.." message box at this time. I use QThread for this but I can not do.

my QThread class

myThread.cpp

```
#include "myThread.h"
#include <QtCore>

myThread::myThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
}

void myThread::run()
{
    emit threadSignal();
}
```

myThread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>

class myThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit myThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void threadSignal();

public slots:

};
```

I wrote in my main header file

```
public:
    myThread *mess;
    QMessageBox box;

public slots:
    void threadSlot();
```

I wrote in my main cpp file:

```
Archive::Archive(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::Archive)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    mess=new myThread(this);
    connect(mess, SIGNAL(threadSignal()), this, SLOT(threadSlot()));
    box.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
}

void Archive::threadSlot()
{
    box.show();
}
```

In my main cpp file there is a function which freeze GUI.

```
void Archive::plot()
{
    mess->start();

    //heavy work. It takes 2-3 second and GUI become unresponsive.

}
```

I want that thread starts firstly and show QmessageBox. after plot() function end, QmessageBox disappeared. But with this code QmessageBox shows after plot() function ends. Why it is behave like this?

I use Qt 4.8.5

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `myThread` object if all the heavy work is being done on the main thread?

Comment: I just want to show a QMessageBox with text "Wait". If I did this in main thread QmessageBox do not appear before GUI freeze.

Comment: Then you should move the heavy work to your `myThread` object and keep the GUI stuff in your main thread, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUI classes in Qt can only be accessed from the main thread.

The official solution to this problem is to do your heavy work in a different thread, and not let your GUI freeze. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html for different ways to use threads in Qt.

**WARNING:** You should ***NOT*** add slots to classes derived from QThread. From the documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html):

> It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old
>   thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run().
>   This means that all of QThread's queued slots will execute in the old
>   thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke slots in the new thread
>   must use the worker-object approach; new slots should not be
>   implemented directly into a subclassed QThread.

These links are for Qt 5, but most of the concepts apply to Qt 4.8 too.